# error producing SVG from sympy / svgmath

Tags: python, svg, mathml, sympy

I am trying to render algebra as an SVG using sympy and svgmath. I have the file 'svgmath.xml' in the root directory. Unfortunately I get: 'ImportError: No module named libxml2'. I'm not sure of the best way to sort this out. I would much appreciate any help/advice. My code is:

```
from xml import sax
from xml.sax.saxutils import XMLGenerator

from svgmath.tools.saxtools import XMLGenerator, ContentFilter
from svgmath.mathhandler import MathHandler, MathNS
from svgmath.tools.saxtools import XMLGenerator

from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml
from sympy.abc import x

from sympy.utilities.mathml import c2p

# Open all files
output = open("test.svg", "w") 
config = open("svgmath.xml", "r")    

# Create the converter as a content handler. 
saxoutput = XMLGenerator(output, 'utf-8')
handler = MathHandler(saxoutput, config)

# Parse input file with a namespace-aware SAX parser
parser = sax.make_parser()
parser.setFeature(sax.handler.feature_namespaces, 1)
parser.setContentHandler(handler)
parser.parse(c2p(mathml(3*x), simple=False))
```

The Stack trace is now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Geddes\my python\SVGmath\test1.py", line 29, in <module>
    parser.parse(c2p(mathml(3*x), simple=True))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 102, in parse
    source = saxutils.prepare_input_source(source)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\saxutils.py", line 298, in prepare_input_source
    f = urllib.urlopen(source.getSystemId())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 84, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 202, in open
    return self.open_unknown(fullurl, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 214, in open_unknown
    raise IOError, ('url error', 'unknown url type', type)
IOError: [Errno url error] unknown url type: '?xml%20version=%221.0%22?%3e%0a%3cmath%20xmlns=%22http'
```

---

My modified code:

```
from xml import sax
from xml.sax.saxutils import XMLGenerator

from svgmath.tools.saxtools import XMLGenerator, ContentFilter
from svgmath.mathhandler import MathHandler, MathNS
from svgmath.tools.saxtools import XMLGenerator

from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml
from sympy.abc import x

from sympy.utilities.mathml import c2p

import libxml2

import StringIO

# Open all files
output = open("test.svg", "w") 
config = open("svgmath.xml", "r")    

# Create the converter as a content handler. 
saxoutput = XMLGenerator(output, 'utf-8')
handler = MathHandler(saxoutput, config)

# Parse input file with a namespace-aware SAX parser
parser = sax.make_parser()
parser.setFeature(sax.handler.feature_namespaces, 1)
parser.setContentHandler(handler)
parser.parse(StringIO.StringIO(mathml(3*x)))
```

This fails to produce a valid SVG file and gives:

```
[WARNING] line 1, column 0: Root element in MathML document must be 'math'
[WARNING] line 1, column 7: MathML element 'times' is unsupported
[WARNING] line 1, column 15: MathML element 'cn' is unsupported
[WARNING] line 1, column 25: MathML element 'ci' is unsupported
[WARNING] line 1, column 0: MathML element 'apply' is unsupported
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the `libxml2` library. For example, on ubuntu this is the `python-libxml2` package. I too tried the sympy -> mathml -> svg route once, I also had to install the package (iirc it's needed for `c2p()`, which applies a XSLT to convert content to presentation MathML).

Comment: Thanks very much I'm just trying that now!

Comment: I now get: IOError: [Errno url error] unknown url type: '?xml%20version=%221.0%22?%3e%0a%3cmath%20xmlns=%22http' - any thoughts?

Comment: Try `parseString` instead of `parse`. The latter takes a filename.

Comment: Thanks again - parseString did not work (gave me: ExpatParser instance has no attribute 'parseString'), but it led me to using StringIO and leaving the c2p (although that might defeat the whole object). No error, but does not produce the SVG.

Comment: I have also tried the line: parser.parse(StringIO.StringIO(c2p(mathml(3*x), simple=True))) which gives: [INFO] line 2, column 0: Ignored attribute 'schemaLocation' from an unknown namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' and also fails to produve the SVG.

Comment: Yes, I hoped that too - c2p is extremely slow, that drove me crazy - but svgmath simply fails to produce an SVG in that case. Using `StringIO` with `parse` should work - but why did it force you to leave out the `c2p()`?

Comment: Ok, comment conflict. Can you paste the output of `c2p`? Maybe it's sufficient to drop the header.

Comment: Ach! Sorry - it did work! It's a shame about c2p being rather slow, but I'm very happy to have got it going! Many many thanks for all your help this evening. All my best wishes.